# Android request often fails when app is in background

Tags: android, http

The request throws java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out.
I use IntentService for executing the request.
I set all the timeouts to 85 seconds. Background data is enabled on the app settings. Power saving mode is off. Data limit is off.
The request is always successful when the app is on foreground. Any ideas?

Here is a code:

```
@Override
public List<EnterExitDeviceGeofenceResult> reportGeofenceEvent(String locationId,
                                                               LatLng latLng, boolean enter)
        throws IOException {
    String enterExitUrlPart = enter ? "/enter" : "/exit";
    String url = getUrl("/users/me/geofences/" + locationId + enterExitUrlPart +
            "?fields=command{resultingAcState,failureReason,status},deviceId", 2);
    String body = generateLatLngRequestBody(latLng);
    return executeCall(
            deserializers.enterExitGeofenceResult(),
            new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(RequestBody.create(JSON, body))
                    .build(),
            getClientBuilder()
                    .addInterceptor(defaultErrorInterceptor)
                    .connectTimeout(REPORT_GEOFENCE_EVENT_TIMEOUT,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(REPORT_GEOFENCE_EVENT_TIMEOUT,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(REPORT_GEOFENCE_EVENT_TIMEOUT,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build()
    );
}

@Nullable
private <T> T executeCall(JsonDeserializer<T> deserializer, Request request,
                          OkHttpClient client) throws IOException {
    if (deserializer == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("deserializer == null");
    }

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(executeCall(request, client));

    try {
        return deserializer.deserialize(new JsonForwardReaderFromJsonReader(new JsonReader(sr)));
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        if (logsEnabled) {
            LogUtil.e(TAG, "Error deserializing", t);
        }
        throw t;
    }
}

private String executeCall(Request request, OkHttpClient client) throws IOException {
    ResponseBody responseBody = null;
    try {
        if (logsEnabled) {
            LogUtil.i(TAG, request.url().toString());
        }
        responseBody = client.newCall(request).execute().body();
        String responseString = responseBody.string();
        if (logsEnabled) {
            LogUtil.i(TAG, String.format("<- %s", responseString));
        }
        return responseString;
    } finally {
        if (responseBody != null) {
            responseBody.close();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    /*some code*/
    restApiClient.reportGeofenceEvent(...);
}
```

Comment: **Quick Tip** : Use any of the popular networking libraries for Android, such as `Retrofit` or `OKHTTP`

Comment: I am using OkHttp actually

Comment: then post the code

Comment: Just posted the code

Comment: you've added internet permission in AndroidManifest right?